# Don't want to show whole LinkedIn link, but only my name

Tags: latex

I want to add linkedin link in latex and I want it to show only my name and logo, not complete link. I am using this line of code.

`\linkedin {https://www.linkedin.com}`

It shows complete link https://www.linkedin.com in pdf also my username is very large and it look odd in pdf. SO I want to show my name instead. I tried googling but didn't find any solution in this reference.

Comment: please make a compilable [mre] that shows is which documentclass etc you use. You probably want to use `\href{<url>}{<name>}`

Answer (score -1):

There are two approaches to solving your problem:

Approach #1: use altacv.cls from git
Then you need to do the following 2 things:

1. in the altacv.cls file: find linkin, then include your linkedin link in the [https://]
2. in your.tex file: do "\linkedin{your name here}"

or

Approach #2: write your own

1. in your.cls file include this line: "\newcommand{linkedin[2]{\infofield{\faLinkedin}{\href{#2}{#1}}}"
   --please note this assumes you have inlcuded the href package and fontawesome5 --
2. in your.tex file: do "\linkedin{your name here}{https to your linkedin profile}

Hope this helps